# Why is my script not showing the correct output?

Tags: php, url, error-handling

I am trying to create a URL shorten script and when the user submits their URL it should return with a text field containing the shortened URL but it isn't, please could you take a look at my code and see if you can stop the problem?

Thanks.

```
<html>
<head></head>

<body>

<?php

if ($_POST['shortbtn']) {
    $url = $_POST['url'];

    if ($url) {

        require("./connect.php");

        $charset = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
        $len = 5;
        $numrows = 1;

        while ($numrows != 0) {
            for ($i = 0; $i <= $len; $i++) {
                $rand = rand() % strlen($charset);
                $tmp = substr($charset, $rand, 1);
                $code .= $tmp;
            }

            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE code='$code'");
            $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
        }

        $date = date("F d, Y");

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO items VALUES('', '$url', '$code', '$date')");

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE code='$code'");
        $numrows= mysql_num_rows($query);

        if ($numrows == 1) {
            $site = "http://dthms.dev:8888/projects/url-short/";
            echo "Your URL: <input type='text' value='$site/$code' size='40'>";
        } else
            echo "Not Added";

        mysql_close();

    } 

    else echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location = './'</script>";
} else echo "";

?>

</body>
</html>
```

At the moment when ever you submit a URL it returns "Not Added"

```
if ($numrows == 1) {
                $site = "http://dthms.dev:8888/projects/url-short/";
                echo "Your URL: <input type='text' value='$site/$code' size='40'>";
            } else
                echo "Not Added";
```

Comment: You should rather check the outcome of your INSERT statement, instead of making another SELECT.

Comment: ...and if you didn't, your `$numrows` could easily go past 1 result while you test this, since you aren't limiting it - you should add `LIMIT 1` to your select query if you don't want to check the insert statement (which you should)

Comment: I would advise against doing a DB lookup until generating a random key returns no results. That could get VERY heavy!

Comment: Please also set `$code='';` before appending to it.

Comment: Also `else echo "";` is pointless. Where is `$date` set?